# Add to stack from ArrayList (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist, stack

I have an ArrayList pre-defined with hardcoded values. How do  I add these to a stack? The idea is to demonstrate the pop, push, peek functions of the stack class.

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

al.add("A");
al.add("B");
al.add("C");

Stack<String> st = new Stack<String>();

st.push(al); **// This doesn't seem to work.. Will I have to loop it in some way?**

System.out.println(st);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can [read the documentation for Stack here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html).  Stacks also implement Collection, so you can also use any of the methods you see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).  It's always a good idea to read the documentation about classes when you use them ;-)

Comment: There's no need to -1 this question. We were all new at this at some point of time.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Like many collection classes, [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) provides a [addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method :

```
st.addAll(al)
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just iterate over array list and push it to stack?

```
for(String str : al)
  st.push(str)
```