# Java : Stack -> ArrayList

Tags: java, stack

Here's what I have so far :

```
System.out.println("\fStack - ArrayList Demo\n");

        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        Stack<String> st = new Stack<String>();

        // Start with a few elements to the ArrayList
        al.add("A");
        al.add("B");
        al.add("C");

        st.addAll(al); // Retrieve ArrayList elements for the stack and add them there
        al.clear(); // Clear arraylist for storage later


        // Pop out the last element in the stack.
        System.out.println("\nPop out the last element: "+al.add(st.pop()));
        System.out.println("What's left of the stack: "+st+"\n");
        System.out.println("ArrayList, now: "+al);

        // Keep popping..
        int count = st.search("A");
       while (count != -1 && count >= 1) {
           System.out.println("Popping next.."+al.add(st.pop()));
           count--;
        }

        // Is the Stack empty?
        System.out.println("\nStack Empty? "+st.empty());
        System.out.println("ArrayList now: "+al);
```

Using `al.add(st.pop()));` returns "true" when I run the program. Is there a way to get it to yield the actual element being popped (A, B, C)?

Comment: String element = st.pop();
System.out.println("element is " + element);
al.add(element);

Comment: String elm = st.pop(); al.add(elm); ?

Comment: @RonDahlgren: and kufudo: You can markup `code` in the comments by surrounding it with backticks: `

Comment: @AC: [your prev. question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646487/add-to-stack-from-arraylist-java) was posted one hour ago. Although we like to help, you'd be better of if you learn to read and understand [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) for add states:

```
Returns:
true (as specified by Collection.add(E))
```

It sounds like you want to print the element you're adding.  So:

```
   String elem = st.pop();
   System.out.println("adding " +elem);
   al.add(elem)
```

If you plan on being a software developer, reading and understanding the documentation is a valuable skill to practice.